# How to resolve js-cookie not saving cart data ReactJS and Redux

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-redux

Hey so I am would love to save the users cart data info within the cart so to cater for page reload to still have the cart's data the the use has picked in cart, I tried implementing but even on refresh the cart info refreshes and takes in the first entered data to cart
can I please get help on resolving thing

**Code below is by cartAction.js**

```
const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const femaleProduct_url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/single-womens-clothes/${productId}`;
    const maleProduct_url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/single-mens-clothes/${productId}`;
    const kidsProduct_url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/single-kids-clothes/${productId}`;

    const femaleProduct_request = await axios.get(femaleProduct_url);
    const maleProudct_request = await axios.get(maleProduct_url);
    const kidsProduct_request = await axios.get(kidsProduct_url);
    let data = [];

    axios
      .all([femaleProduct_request, maleProudct_request, kidsProduct_request])
      .then(
        axios.spread((...responses) => {
          const f_product = responses[0];
          const m_product = responses[1];
          const k_product = responses[2];

          if (f_product.data.length > 0) {
            data = f_product.data;
          } else if (m_product.data.length > 0) {
            data = m_product.data;
          } else {
            data = k_product.data;
          }
        })
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(data[0].productName);
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_TO_CART,
          payload: {
            productId: data[0]._id,
            name: data[0].productName,
            image: data[0].productImage,
            price: data[0].productPrice,
            Qty: qty,
          },
        });

        //This is where I tried to set the cart data to the user's cookie
        const {
          cart: { cartItems },
        } = getState();
        Cookie.set("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
```

**Code below is the store.js where I set initalized the state by getting the  cookie data stated at Actions.js**

```
const cart = Cookie.getJSON("cartItems" || []);
const initialState = { cartItems: cart };
const reducer = combineReducers({
  femaleClothesList: femaleProductListReducer,
  maleClothesList: maleProductListReducer,
  kidsClothesList: kidsProductListReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});
```

Can I please get help with resolving this problem

Comment: If you `console.log(cartItems)` above where you are trying to set it, does it display the correct data?

Comment: I get this warning from console..

```Cookie “cartItems” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite```

Comment: But I really doubt that this warning has anything to do with the problem that I am facing